# How to insert array data into mysql db from instagram api response using php?

Tags: php, instagram

I am calling instagram api and getting a response as an array inside $record.

I wonder how I can get username, first_name, profile_picture, id, last_name variables from $record and insert them into mysql db if they are not already in mysql db? Could any one show me how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

According to [Instagram API Docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows) the following api:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXX/follows?access_token==XXXX&count=-1
```

edited : Now i can print the array variables but how to insert them into mysql db and avoid duplication?

```
foreach($record->data as $user) // each user data (JSON array) defined as $user
{
echo "User Name:".$user->username;
echo "<br>Bio:".$user->bio;
echo "<br>Website:".$user->website;
echo "<br>Profile Picture:".$user->profile_picture;
echo "<br>Full Name:".$user->full_name;
echo "<br>id:".$user->id;
echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Returns:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "username": "washington",
        "first_name": "George",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_6623_75sq.jpg",
        "id": "1",
        "last_name": "Washington"
    },
    {
        "username": "SammyDavis",
        "first_name": "Sammy",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_29648_75sq_1294520029.jpg",
        "id": "29648",
        "last_name": "Davis"
    },
    {
        "username": "FrankTheTank",
        "first_name": "Frank",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_13096_75sq_1286441317.jpg",
        "id": "13096",
        "last_name": "Roberts"
    }]
}
```

php script:

```
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXX/follows?access_token==XXXX&count=-1";
$api_response = get_data(''.$url);
$record = json_decode($api_response); // JSON decode 

//now i want to get username,first_name,profile_picture,id,last_name variables and insert it into mysql db


/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($record->data as $rows){
    //now you can get vars from $rows
    $username = $rows->username;
}
```

Comment: thanks now how i can insert all these variables into mysql inside this foreach loop (first checking for username or id if already exist i don't insert that record)?$username,$first_name,$profile_picture,$id,$last_name